# How can I ensure that a resource is a dbpedia-owl:Person?

Tags: rdf, sparql, dbpedia

How  can I ensure that a resource is a dbpedia-owl:Person? Currently I have a a pattern like the following.  What can I add to this query to ensure that each `?node` is also a `dbpedia-owl:Person`?

```
?node dbpedia-owl:something ?edge .
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I [replied on the DBpedia mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=31775892), you can use something like

```
select * where {
  ?influencer dbpedia-owl:influenced ?influencee .
  dbpedia-owl:Person ^a ?influencer, ?influencee .
}
```

That uses some syntactic sugar that SPARQL defines, but without it, it's simply

```
select * where {
  ?influencer dbpedia-owl:influenced ?influencee .
  ?influencer a dbpedia-owl:Person .
  ?influencee a dbpedia-owl:Person .
}
```

It doesn't matter which order you put the triple patterns in.  E.g., you could also write

```
select * where {
  ?influencer a dbpedia-owl:Person .
  ?influencer dbpedia-owl:influenced ?influencee .
  ?influencee a dbpedia-owl:Person .
}
```

or

```
select * where {
  ?influencer a dbpedia-owl:Person .
  ?influencee a dbpedia-owl:Person .
  ?influencer dbpedia-owl:influenced ?influencee .
}
```

RDF is a graph based data representation, and a graph is a *set* of directed edges.  The order of triples in the pattern doesn't matter.